# Discord.py: How to wait for new message in channel and use its content for another embed

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been building a bot with some special commands recently.

APPEAL command is the one which has the problem right now.

#### What's the work of the command?

It has to send an embed and mention what all stuff has to be entered in channel for the BOT to get it. That is it for the bot.

#### Code:

````py
@nd.command()
async def appeal(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id == 836811104424296480:
        appealinfoembed=discord.Embed(title="Appeal", description=f"Hi {ctx.author.mention}, you are appealing for verification. Now, the verification system works like this, unless you are verified, you can't send messages in the server except this category. So, if you are a town member and you want to send messages and use other features, then get verified. Thus, use this command. \n \nYou need to submit the following data in order to get verified. This data will be looked over by our Town Council and they will verify you soon. This is the format: \n```Real Name: \nIn game name: \nAge: \nSex: M/F/T \n \nTown Joing Date: \nExperience: 'Add you experience in the Towny Servers, anywhere you played, in brief.'```", color=discord.Colour.random())
        appealinfoembed.set_author(name="xXMiaraXx")
        appealinfoembed.set_footer(text=datetime.datetime.now())
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=appealinfoembed)
        
        await ctx.channel.send("Your next message after this text will be considered as the information asked before. Please enter all the details in one single message, otherwise the verification will not work.")

        appealchannel = nd.get_channel(836811104424296480)
        
        if member_details == await appealchannel.fetch_message(appealchannel.last_message_id):
            memberdetailsembed=discord.Embed(title=f"Appeal by - {ctx.author.mention}", description=member_details, color=discord.Colour.random())
            memberdetailsembed.set_author(name="xXMiaraXx")
            memberdetailsembed.set_footer(text=datetime.datetime.now())
            await appealchannel.send(embed=memberdetailsembed)

    else:
        return
````

#### Problem:

The code above appealchannel variable works fine as it is correct but anything after it does not work. It just doesn't do anything. Any message posted after it not taken in or I don't know what happens. I am not getting where the error actually is.

---

The answers may not necessarily made on this code's type. Please just do anything to make it clear to me and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that your bot gets the newest message in the channel right when it wrote it message, and nobody can type so fast. To fix this, you can use `wait_for()`, add this before `appealchannel = nd.get_channel(836811104424296480)`:

```py
def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
try:
    answer = await nd.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=600.0)#you can add any timeout in seconds there, for an appeal bot I would recommend something like 15 minutes
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send("Your time is up") #Do stuff here when the time runs out
```

This should fix your problem, since I don't know where you get the variable member_details from. So instead of member_details, use answer.content and remove the `if member_details == await appealchannel.fetch_message(appealchannel.last_message_id):`
So your final code would be:

````py
@nd.command()
async def appeal(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id == 836811104424296480:
        appealinfoembed=discord.Embed(title="Appeal", description=f"Hi {ctx.author.mention}, you are appealing for verification. Now, the verification system works like this, unless you are verified, you can't send messages in the server except this category. So, if you are a town member and you want to send messages and use other features, then get verified. Thus, use this command. \n \nYou need to submit the following data in order to get verified. This data will be looked over by our Town Council and they will verify you soon. This is the format: \n```Real Name: \nIn game name: \nAge: \nSex: M/F/T \n \nTown Joing Date: \nExperience: 'Add you experience in the Towny Servers, anywhere you played, in brief.'```", color=discord.Colour.random())
        appealinfoembed.set_author(name="xXMiaraXx")
        appealinfoembed.set_footer(text=datetime.datetime.now())
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=appealinfoembed)
        
        await ctx.channel.send("Your next message after this text will be considered as the information asked before. Please enter all the details in one single message, otherwise the verification will not work.")
        def check(msg):
                return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
        try:
            answer = await nd.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=600.0)#you can add any timeout in seconds there, for an appeal bot I would recommend something like 15 minutes
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Your time is up") #Do stuff here when the time runs out
        memberdetailsembed=discord.Embed(title=f"Appeal by - {ctx.author.mention}", description=answer.content, color=discord.Colour.random())
        memberdetailsembed.set_author(name="xXMiaraXx")
        memberdetailsembed.set_footer(text=datetime.datetime.now())
        appealchannel = nd.get_channel(836811104424296480)
        await appealchannel.send(embed=memberdetailsembed)
````

### References:

- [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Comment: This is the perfect fix, OP could also wait for 30 seconds before fetching the message, if he **really wants to use** `fetch_message`

Comment: The problem with that would be, that P1 would write the appeal after 20 seconds and P2 would write another message, the latest message would be from P2 @Ceres

Comment: Yep, using `wait_for` is way better than fetch_message in this case

Comment: also, your channel id should be the appeal channel id, not ctx in the check

Comment: it's the same, as they used `ctx.channel.send` to send in the same channel the answer is written in @Ceres

Comment: I thought that they used the appeal_channel to fetch the message. my bad

Comment: Actually both are the same channels. This command will not work in any other channel than the one specified. So works both ways.

Comment: @Chuaat It doesn't work. I mean it works till the embed and message just like mentioned above but nothing happen after it.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav Are you sure you included all of your code in the question? Since the variable member_details is used, but not declared, so I was wondering... Also do you get any error messages, are you sure you are writing in the same channel the bot asked you, and it's not a DM?

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav I just added one important line, test it out now again

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. Just like I want it too. You are great.

Comment: One more doubt. I wanted it to delete the previous three messages that were posted. Two by the Bot and One by the Member. I have a clear() command for bulk message deletion. So would it work if I just did `await clear(3)`?

Comment: I checked it doesn't work. Just help me out with this. How do I delete those previous three messages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231704/discussion-between-chuaat-and-bhavyadeep-yadav).